# Can you still defrag Vista if you use Wubi?

Tags: 10.04, wubi, defrag

Would like to defrag Vista seperately,understanding that Ubuntu does not need it. While Ubuntu files are included on the c drive will it cause problems?

Answer (score 9):

Wubi creates a virtual disk (the same as any VM, like VirtualBox or VMWare) which can be defragmented within Windows just like any other file. Feel free to defragment in Vista - it won't affect wubi.

Comment: You may even get better Wubi performance... (you certainly won't experience problems)